# Create a Groovy executable JAR with Gradle

Tags: groovy, gradle

This is my gradle build script.

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

project.group = "test.tree"
archivesBaseName = "tree"
project.version = "1.0"
manifest.mainAttributes("Main-Class" : "test.tree.App")

sourceCompatibility=1.6
targetCompatibility=1.6

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    groovy group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy', version: '1.8.6'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.8.2'
}
```

And this compiles just fine

The problem is that I can't run the created JAR, I get an exception
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/GroovyObject`

So I guess the groovy plugin doesn't include all the necessary classes inside the JAR.

How to I create a stand-alone JAR that I can simply .. run ;-)

Comment: After reading all the tips from here and also using http://github.com/AvatarQing/groovy-executable-jar-with-gradle-example, I created a jar file that takes a groovy script and creates executable jar: https://github.com/krishnact/uberifier. The jar file is: https://github.com/krishnact/uberifier/blob/master/bin/Uberifier-1.0.0.jar?raw=true

Answer (score 49, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [application plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) which allows you build a standalone JVM application including all dependencies and run scripts.

```
apply plugin:'application'
mainClassName = 'test.tree.App'
```

**EDIT:**

This should create the uberjar you want:

```
task uberjar(type: Jar) {
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
    from configurations.runtime.asFileTree.files.collect { zipTree(it) }

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'test.tree.App'
    }
}
```

Comment: This is nice, I like the `distZip` task, but what I want is smt like `distJar` task -> a tast that creates an executable JAR with all necessary classes (mine, groovy rt ... ) inside.

Comment: I'd recommend keeping your application classes separate from external dependencies. If you'd really wanted to create an uberjar [this is how you can do it](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin/blob/master/build.gradle#L26). Of course you'd use the external dependencies instead of the subprojects.

Comment: Created a sample project based on code provided by @Benjamin: https://github.com/bond-/gradle-groovy-jar-example

Comment: @Raviteja I can make a jar from your project using the latest Gradle but when I try to run the jar it says could not find or load main class Test. Any advice?

Comment: @AnonymousHuman this was broken by Gradle 4. Try gradle 3.5. That's the best I can offer right now.

Comment: The only missing part is `dependsOn: compileGroovy` for `uberjar` task, and everything should work, as it's working for me.

Comment: I think there is a typo in the  from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir), I think it should be  from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs) (note the ending 's')

Comment: @EnriqueWood The API changed with a newer version of Gradle. It's not a typo.

Answer (score 1):

I would throw in a vote for the [shadow gradle plugin](http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/). It is capable of building uber jars and is quite versatile and capable of things like class relocation to prevent [dependency hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell).

I will not get into comparing the two plugins, but I will go as far as saying that I have gravitated towards using shadow from having used application in the past because of the added features.

When I get tired of the startup times of @Grab based groovy scripts, I tend to write a gradle build file using the shadow plugin even for single file groovy scripts. An example gradle build file capable of building an uber jar of a groovy script file in the current directory. The main class name needs to correspond to the script file name:

```
repositories { 
  jcenter()
  mavenCentral()
}

defaultTasks = ['shadowJar']
version      = "1.0"

dependencies {
  compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.7", 
          "commons-cli:commons-cli:1.2"
}

sourceSets {
  main {
    groovy {
        srcDirs = [rootDir]
    }
  }
}

project.tasks.remove jar

shadowJar {
  manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'MyGroovyScriptName'
  }

  classifier = ""
}
```

the uber jar will be generated in the `build/libs` directory.

Answer (score 0):

**the following code is also ok**,use spring boot plugin

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.2.6.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'


sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


sourceSets {
    main {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['src']
        }
    }

    /*test {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['test/groovy']
        }
    }*/
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.alibaba:fastjson:1.1.34"
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.5'
    //testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.8.2'
}
springBoot {
    backupSource = false
    mainClass = "com.zhb.hello.Hello"
}
jar{
    baseName = 'hellogroovy'
    version = '1.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, after adding jar block in build.gradle then it works.

```
jar {
  manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'demo.Demo'
  }
  from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you post an answer, try to comment it. In your case, even, it doesn´t seem an answer.