# Gradle won't run, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/GroovyObject

Tags: groovy, gradle

I'm trying to do a basic build with Gradle. Even `gradle -v` fails with the following:

```
$ gradle -v

FAILURE: Build aborted because of an internal error.

* What went wrong:
Build aborted because of an unexpected internal error. Please file an issue at: http://www.gradle.org.

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get additional debug info.

* Exception is:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/GroovySystem
    at org.gradle.util.GradleVersion.prettyPrint(GradleVersion.java:183)
    at org.gradle.launcher.CommandLineActionFactory$ShowVersionAction.run(CommandLineActionFactory.java:181)
    at org.gradle.launcher.CommandLineActionFactory$ActionAdapter.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:199)
    at org.gradle.launcher.CommandLineActionFactory$ActionAdapter.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:191)
(stacktrace snipped)
at org.gradle.launcher.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:28)
at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.lang.GroovySystem
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    ... 17 more
```

So, I thought "aha, my classpath is empty. Let me add groovy".

```
$ export CLASSPATH=/usr/share/gradle/lib/groovy-all.jar && echo $CLASSPATH
/usr/share/gradle/lib/groovy-all.jar
```

No difference.

For what it's worth, here's the build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    groovy group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy', version: '1.7.10'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.8.2'
}
```

The only relevant stackoverflow question I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749032/create-a-groovy-executable-jar-with-gradle), and google wasn't much better.

The [install doc for gradle](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/installation.html) says "Gradle ships with its own Groovy library, therefore no Groovy needs to be installed." That implies the classpath would be unnecessary. So why can't I run it?

Comment: When you run gradle -v -debug do you get any further clues.

Comment: No @Rob, it just prefixes each line, same error. I'll probably just install a known version (as said), but that doesn't explain what is actually wrong, it's just a cargo cult solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a corrupted Gradle installation. Maybe you aren't calling the `gradle` script you think you are.