# Groovy: How to convert .groovy to .exe

Tags: groovy, exe

Please, provide simplest way to convert .groovy-script to executable file .exe for windows-platform or .jar, for using on multiply platforms.

Thanks

Comment: This might be of help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749032/create-a-groovy-executable-jar-with-gradle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Jar**

[This project](https://github.com/peidevs/WarO_Groovy) is a simple card game, written in Groovy. It is uses a [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) script to build a zip file that can be executed like so:

```
unzip warO.zip
java -jar warO.jar
```

See this segment of the build.gradle file to see how the manifest is specified for the jar (i.e. the classpath, main class entry point, etc):

```
jar.archiveName 'warO.jar'
jar.manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class' : 'net.codetojoy.waro.Main' 
    attributes 'Class-Path' : 'jars/groovy-all-1.6.4.jar jars/guava-collections-r03.jar jars/guava-base-r03.jar'
}
```

**Exe**

For an exe, consider a tool such as [JWrapper](http://www.jwrapper.com/).