# Running a Gradle compiled Java application with dependencies via the java command

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

I’m trying to compile the Code Example 3 from [this article explaining the Swing Application Framework (JSR 296)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-141957.html) with [Gradle](http://gradle.org/) and to run it from the command line with the `java` command.

My directory layout looks like this:

```
├── build.gradle
└── src/
    └── main/
        └── java/
            └── demo/
                └── BasicSingleFrameApp.java
```

The `build.gradle` file defines a dependency to the `appframework`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile 'org.jdesktop:appframework:1.0.3'
}
```

And this is the `BasicSingleFrameApp.java` file, a copy of the example of the article mentioned above, enhanced by a package declaration:

```
package demo;

import org.jdesktop.application.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class BasicSingleFrameApp extends SingleFrameApplication {
    JLabel label;

    @Override
    protected void startup() {
        getMainFrame().setTitle("BasicSingleFrameApp");
        label = new JLabel("Hello, world!");
        label.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 22));
        show(label);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(BasicSingleFrameApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

Compiling with `gradle build` works fine and without errors.

But when I then try to run the `BasicSingleFrameApp` with

```
$ java -cp build/classes/main/ demo.BasicSingleFrameApp
```

I get the error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class demo.BasicSingleFrameApp
```

When I replace the `BasicSingleFrameApp` class with a simple “Hello, world!” printing class without dependencies, everything works fine.

I’m confused, because in my understanding I correctly set up the classpath and I don’t understand why the `main` method (which has the right signature) cannot be found.

This is my Java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)
```

which I am running an Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.2.

Comment: are you sure the desktop jsr jar is on the classpath?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific, please? Gradle reports (via `gradle dependencies`) that the “Compile classpath for source set 'main'”  contains `org.jdesktop:appframework:1.0.3` and `org.jdesktop:swing-worker:1.1`. The same for “Runtime classpath for source set 'main'”.

Comment: (Almost) exact same problem as me. I'm flabbergasted by how complicated this is with Gradle...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so @chuchikaeschtli helped me to get to the core of the problem, namely that Gradle manages dependencies for compiling and reports to do so for runtime, but more manual tasks are required to make these dependencies available during runtime.

What still confuses me is the unintuitive error message I got:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class demo.BasicSingleFrameApp
```

I would have expected a problem that has to do with missing dependencies at runtime to report an error like

```
error: package org.jdesktop.application does not exist
```

which is the kind of error I get when these dependencies are missing at compile time.

And as Gradle gave me the following report about runtime dependencies (by running `gradle dependencies`) I thought that Gradle somehow manages these:

```
compile - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
\--- org.jdesktop:appframework:1.0.3
     \--- org.jdesktop:swing-worker:1.1
…
runtime - Runtime classpath for source set 'main'.
\--- org.jdesktop:appframework:1.0.3
     \--- org.jdesktop:swing-worker:1.1
…
```

In the end, after knowing that it is a problem of missing runtime dependencies I found several ways to provide them, which I will share.

***First solution: Linking to the cache***

As stated in [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10834567/100215) Gradle caches dependencies in `$HOME/.gradle`, but the actual path to them is tricky. The answer describes a small Gradle task that outputs the full path of each dependency in the cache (in this example for the `compile` configuration, which is what I need):

```
task showMeCache << {
  configurations.compile.each { println it }
}
```

In my case `gradle showMeCache` reports:

```
$HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jdesktop/appframework/1.0.3/338045feff6e61df237aafd11b6f3fe1a3b4e60e/appframework-1.0.3.jar
$HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jdesktop/swing-worker/1.1/dc9f8d6f7236087924aad28fbec794a087dd1b3d/swing-worker-1.1.jar
```

These are long and nasty file paths, but I’m able to construct a `java` command that works in the style @chuchikaeschtli suggested:

```
java \
-cp build/classes/main/\
:$HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jdesktop/appframework/1.0.3/338045feff6e61df237aafd11b6f3fe1a3b4e60e/appframework-1.0.3.jar\
:$HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jdesktop/swing-worker/1.1/dc9f8d6f7236087924aad28fbec794a087dd1b3d/swing-worker-1.1.jar \
demo.BasicSingleFrameApp
```

This works, but of course this does not feel very “right”. But it helps to understand the problem: it was really a matter of missing dependency jars.

***Second solution: Syncing dependencies to the `build` directory***

In the section [Using the Sync task of the Gradle User Guide](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:sync_task) it explicitly uses an example that describes a better solution to the problem at hand:

> Here is an example which maintains a copy of the project's runtime dependencies in the build/libs directory.

```
task libs(type: Sync) {
  from configurations.runtime
  into "$buildDir/libs"
}
```

After running this task with `gradle libs` I’m able to construct a much simpler working `java` command:

```
java -cp build/classes/main/:build/libs/appframework-1.0.3.jar:build/libs/swing-worker-1.1.jar demo.BasicSingleFrameApp
```

Remember: these dependencies haven’t been synced into the `build` directory by default!

***Third solution: Using Gradle to run the application***

With the [Application Plugin](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) Gradle itself provides a convenient solution to running an application. After adding these two lines to my `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin:'application'

mainClassName = 'demo.BasicSingleFrameApp'
```

I was able to succesfully start the application with just `gradle run`. Simplest solution so far!

Note that the application plugin also delivers a task named `installDist` that within `build/install` creates a runnable distribution of the app and all its dependencies, complete with start scripts for UNIX and Windows systems. This has the advantage that Gradle is not needed for execution of the application.

Also, if you like the `gradle run` task of the Application Plugin but are concerned about whether Gradle is available at the target system, have a look at the [Gradle Wrapper](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html).

***Fourth solution: Creating a [One-JAR](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/), Fat Jar, or Uber Jar***

There seem to exist [Gradle-only ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749032/create-a-groovy-executable-jar-with-gradle/9749869#9749869) and [Gradle plugins](https://github.com/rholder/gradle-one-jar) that help with the creation of these jars that include all of the required dependencies for the application.

In the case of the [gradle-one-jar-Plugin](https://github.com/rholder/gradle-one-jar) the application can then be started with a `java` command like:

```
java -jar build/libs/YOUR_APP_NAME-standalone.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

from what I get is that you are starting the app just using java so you have to tell java where to find the swing application framework jar you downloaded. so the command should look something like

```
java -cp pathtojdektopjar/jdesktopjar.jar;build/classes/main/ demo.BasicSingleFrameApp
```