# Eclipse not compiling Groovy scripts into java classes at runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy

Strangely I am not having any compile-time error but while running the application I am getting NoClassDefFound error for Groovy classes.

I am using Eclipse 3.6 with Groovy 2.7.0 plugin. I have Groovy 1.8.5 installed on my machine and groovy-all.jar is in my classpath of application.

I can see all the groovy files in WEB-INF/classes folder with .groovy extension not with .class extension.

What I am missing here?

Comment: How are you compiling? How are you running it? What's on your classpath? What's in your Jar?

Comment: What version of Eclipse? What version of Groovy? Up to date Groovy plugin? ...*sigh*...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. You project is not a groovy project and so your groovy files are being treated as resources (not sources).  Resources are copied to the output folder, whereas sources are compiled.  Make sure that your project icon has a little *GR* symbol on it.
2. Or perhaps you have inadvertently enabled script folders for the source folder where your groovy files are located.  Go to Preferences -> Groovy -> Compiler and look at the section on Groovy Script Folders.  Note that Groovy Script folders can also be configured on a per-project basis, so you may also need to look at Project -> Properties -> Groovy Compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are executing the code using `groovy` and not `java`. Otherwise, you will have to link the groovy.jar file in your classpath. See this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/378905/845279).